# How to design implementation of errors and exceptions in nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, system-design

I am building an sdk and using nestjs for it,

Use case: trying to build a errors and exceptions module server for it,

I have some questions:

1. we do not require exception mappers like java in nestjs?
2. i have to create app_yml file which will load at the time of bootstrapping in which user gives its error message which will override nestjs error message or object what the best way to design it ?
3. For the custom exception handling what should be best way it would be either interceptor creating and using it in controller.